GitLab Personal Access Token Update/Authentication Error on Tower
I have created a personal access token on gitlab to use within tower. I think the existing one expired and I created a new one. When I go into my GitLab Account on Tower to update the token it gives error below:

How can I update the personal access token for gitlab on Tower in another way?
I updated the personal access token on gitlab and wanted to update it within tower as well.
